# Beamer: Hyperlink to specific slide in frame with specific after\pause on the slide?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, presentations

I jump to different frames using hyperlinks and beamer buttons as:

```
\hyperlink{label}{\beamerbutton{text}}
```

However, is there is a way to jump to a specific slide (label) after a certain \pause in it. Say I have 3 \pause points in "label" slide, like"

```
\pause 
 sd
\pause 
 ff
\pause
```

I want to jump to "label" slide after the 3rd slide. Please, help me with this issue.

Answer (score -1):

In `beamer` do not use `\label` for `hyperlinks`! Use `\hypertarget{label}{}` and time it with `\only<3->{}`. Don't forget to load `package` `hyperref`!

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second}
Kísértet járja be Európát – a kommunizmus kísértete. Szent hajszára szövetkezett e kísértet ellen a régi Európának minden hatalma: a pápa és a cár, Metternich és Guizot, francia radikálisok és német rendőrök.
\pause

Akad-e ellenzéki párt, amelyről kormányon levő ellenfelei nem híresztelték, hogy kommunista, akad-e ellenzéki párt, amelyik nem vágta vissza a kommunizmus megbélyegző vádját a haladottabb ellenzékieknek éppúgy, mint reakciós ellenfeleinek?
\pause

Ebből a tényből két dolog következik.\only<3->{\hypertarget{alma}{}}
\pause

A kommunizmust immár az összes európai hatalmak hatalomnak ismerik el.
\pause

Legfőbb ideje, hogy a kommunisták az egész világ előtt nyíltan kifejtsék nézeteiket, céljaikat, törekvéseiket, és a kommunizmus kísértetéről szóló mesékkel magának a pártnak a kiáltványát állítsák szembe.
\pause

Evégből a legkülönbözőbb nemzetiségű kommunisták összegyűltek Londonban, és papírra vetették a következő kiáltványt, amelyet angol, francia, német, olasz, flamand és dán nyelven tesznek közzé.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Thirdth}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Fourth}
\hyperlink{alma}{\beamerbutton{Jump to}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```